# All modules except php-mysql are installed in phpinfo

Tags: linux, mysql, php, centos6.4

I executed all sort of yum install commands and installed all packages.

```
[root@myip php.d]#  rpm -qa | grep -i mysql
mysql-server-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
mysql-devel-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
mysql-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
```

But in phpinfo i can see all extensions like mssql , pgsql , mongo etc but not `mysql`

what should i do

PHP pacakges

```
php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pgsql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-imagick-2.2.2-4.el6.x86_64
php-zts-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-process-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-ldap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-suhosin-0.9.29-2.el6.x86_64
php-enchant-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-fpm-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
php-odbc-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-xdebug-2.1.4-1.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-geoip-1.0.8-3.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
php-embedded-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-soap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-snmp-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-bcmath-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-imap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-xmlrpc-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-gd-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-xml-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-recode-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-mssql-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64
php-pecl-mongo-1.4.0-1.el6.x86_64
php-tidy-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64
php-dba-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-intl-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pspell-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-3.el6.noarch
php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: So what does `phpinfo()` look like?

Comment: every module is listed there except mysql

Comment: is `extension=m_mysql` uncommented in php.ini?

Comment: @NathanC . there is no extension=m_mysql in ini file. system says that all fil;es are in etc/php.d directory and all r loaded from there. i have same file on localhost and it works there. extensins are now in their separate ini files

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed php-MySQL, and assuming you're using Apache, you might just need to restart Apache (if you haven't already).

I believe in centos, that's:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: i did that many times

Comment: Gotcha - Are my assumptions right about what you installed? (Are you building a LAMP stack? - can you list relevant installed packages?)

Comment: i have added php packes, what else u want to knopw